# How to move shape background image with the shape in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to map out skills and interests of team members in a force-directed graph.

The basic structure is mapped out. Instead of names written next to the circles, I'd like to have the circles contain photos of the persons, if available.

The call to `.force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())` lets my shapes re-orient them selves during the initialization. This is causing some weird repeat effect on the background-image, since this is not moving with the shape.

Here is the complete code, which is also available as a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k20mevrL/1/):

```
var width = 640,
    height = 480;

    var team = [
        {name: "User 1", skills: ["C#", "Typescript", ".Net", "ArcGIS"]},
        {name: "User 2", skills: ["Project Management", "Candy Crush", ".Net"]},
        {name: "User 3", skills: ["C#", "Javascript", ".Net"]},
        {name: "User 4", skills: ["Consulting", "Release Management", "Xml"]},
        {name: "User 5", skills: ["Consulting", "Powerpoint"]},
        {name: "User 6", skills: ["Cold Fusion", "ArcGIS", "SQL Server"]},

    ];

    var links = [];
    team.forEach((member, idx) => {
        member.skills.forEach(skill => {
            //foreach skill iterate over each member and find fitting matches
          team.forEach((memberToCompare, idx2) => {
              var compareIndex = memberToCompare.skills.indexOf(skill)
            //   console.log(member.name, idx, skill, "---",memberToCompare.name, memberToCompare.skills[compareIndex], idx2, compareIndex);
            if(compareIndex !== -1 && idx !== idx2) {
                links.push({source: idx, target: idx2, value: skill})
            }
          })
        })
      })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.append("g").attr("class", "nodes");
svg.append("g").attr("class", "links");

var defs = svg.append('svg:defs');

defs.append("svg:pattern")
    .attr("id", "grump_avatar")
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 40)
    .attr("patternUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
    .append("svg:image")
    .attr("xlink:href", 'http://placekitten.com/g/40/40')
    .attr("width", 40)
    .attr("height", 40);

var force = d3.forceSimulation(team)
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().links(links)
        .distance(150)
    // .strength(-1)
    )
    .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody())
    .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))
    //.force('collision', d3.forceCollide().radius((d) => { return d.radius; }))
    .on('tick', ticked);



function ticked() {
    updateLinks();
    var u = d3.select('svg')
        .selectAll('circle')
        .data(team)

    u.enter()
        .append('circle')
        .attr('r', 20)
        .merge(u)
        .attr('cx', function (d) {
            return d.x
        })
        .attr('cy', function (d) {
            return d.y
        })
        .style("fill", "#fff")
        .style("fill", "url(#grump_avatar)");

    u.exit().remove()
}

function updateLinks() {
    var u = d3.selectAll(".links")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(links);

    u.enter()
        .append("path")
        .merge(u)
        .attr("d", (d) => {
            var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
                dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
                dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
            return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
        })
        .attr("class", "link");

    u.exit().remove();
}
```

How can I make the background-image stick to the shape itself, so it moves with the shape containing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to change `patternUnits` to `objectBoundingBox`:

```
.attr("patternUnits", "objectBoundingBox")
```

Using this, causes the image to use the coordinates inside the shape it is used, isntead of the whole svg element where it is defined.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/patternUnits